# can't display column in for-each loop after left join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm running this query on my item table

```
SELECT item.*, status.status_id  FROM item LEFT JOIN status ON item.status = status.id
```

[image]

```
<?php foreach ($itemqedit as $myitem) : ?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><?= $myitem['item_desc'] ?></td>
                                            <td><?= $myitem['display'] ?></td>
                                            <td><?= $myitem['brand'] ?></td>
                                            <td><?= $myitem['model'] ?></td>
                                            <td><?= $myitem['spec'] ?></td>
                                            <td><?= $myitem['sn'] ?></td>
                                            <td><?= $myitem['set_name'] ?></td>
                                            <td><img src="items-img/<?= $myitem['item_pic'] ?>" style="width: 50px"></td>
                                            <td><?= $myitem['date_add'] ?></td>
                                            <td><?= $myitem['status_id'] ?></td>
                                            <td><a class="paginate_button current" href="itemedit.php?itmid=<?= $myitem['id'] ?>"> <button class="btn btn-info pull-left" > עריכה</button> </a> </td>
                                        </tr>
```

the query is running fine and I get the desired result

I'm also running for each loop with this query and I can display all the columns except the `status_id` that is coming from `status` table

> Notice: Undefined index: status_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\ch10nb\edititem.php on line 94

What am I doing wrong? In the phpmyadmin when I run this query I get no error and I can see that the `status_id` has been added to the item table but I can't display it.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: verify table column, is it `ststus_id` or `status_id`? Because you mentioned both above.

Comment: sorry it was miss spell on my post

Comment: Show your php code where you get the error.

Comment: Are you sure, you are getting `status_id` index in variable `$itemqedit`. Verify once by `print_r()` the records before executing loop.

Comment: you are right i am not getting it in the array Array ( [id] => 95 [item_desc] => מיק.אלחוטי [display] => W.L Sony [brand] => sony [model] => [spec] => משדר [sn] => wl3 [set_name] => wl03 [status] => 3 [item_pic] => [date_add] => 2018-12-12 17:21:42.509946 ) how can i fix this??

Comment: if your above query works well then try with these using alias name for `status_id` as `SELECT item.*, (status.status_id) as statusID  FROM item LEFT JOIN status ON item.status = status.id`

Comment: still not working...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185154/discussion-between-saddam-and-dror-shalit).

Answer (score 0):

try adding an alias

```
SELECT item.*
    , status.status_id   AS  status_id
FROM item 
LEFT JOIN status ON item.status = status.id
```

Comment: update your question add  the table schema a proper data sample  .. the actual result and the expected  result

Comment: Array ( [id] => 95 [item_desc] => מיק.אלחוטי [display] => W.L Sony [brand] => sony [model] => [spec] => משדר [sn] => wl3 [set_name] => wl03 [status] => 3 [item_pic] => [date_add] => 2018-12-12 17:21:42.509946 ) it is not in the array,,, how can i fix this??

Comment: show the code where you populate  the $itemqedit  ..result

Comment: This answer should have worked, have you tried putting the foreach loop between curly braces, and echoing each <td> cell??

Comment: try using **SELECT item.*
    , status.status_id status_id**